# How to fire an event from a React component and catch it wtih node/express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to React and I am trying to get some practice in by making a little Full Stack application consisting of a React Frontend and Express server for the Backend.

I want to create a button in a React component, that when pressed fires a function in the Express Server file. The reason is, I want to send POST/GET requests via the server to another REST API but only when the button is pressed by a user in the Frontend.

**My Question is:** What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Send a request to the back end on button press? I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hi there, "the best way" to quote your question is an **opinion** - please post some code using your **ideal way** and post questions *with code* that we can help find errors in to guide you. Here's a couple of links that might help you: (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)[React Events Documentation], (Fetch API)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to connect your frontend application to your Express server.
Now they can communicate using Websockets, SSE etc. but considering you're new, I'll cover client pull mechanism.

**Steps**:

1. You need to expose one api from your Express Server.
2. The react application will have a button with onClick event.
3. On clicking, it will fire a function. This function will make an api call to your Express endpoint (defined in step 1).
4. The handler which you've defined in the Express application will in turn call another Rest API (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

1)Make a GET/POST request in your backend and have it to request the data from another API that you need to fetch the data from. Assign the returned data to a variable then place this variable inside your POST/GET request's res.send() . 2) In your React component before "return()" make a function that sends Axios request to your endpoint you mentioned in your backend. And assign the response value to your state. 3)Make a button element in your "return()"  you need an onClick event. Call your function inside this onClick event.
Note that you will need to install axios npm package and import it.